# aperiodic auto correlation properties

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, synchronization

I'm reading about PSC (primary synchronization code) in UMTS. It is a so-called Golay sequence.
It is said it has a good **aperiodic** auto correlation properties.

What does it mean (in terms of aperiodic)?

What is the difference between good periodic/aperiodic auto correlation properties?

How does it differ from good cross-correlation properties?

The questions ares not about PSC in UMTS in particular. It's rather about terminology

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More than you probably want to know about aperiodic and periodic correlation properties of sequences in general can be found in the paper "Crosscorrelation properties of pseudorandom and related sequences," _Proc. IEEE_, May 1980, by myself and M. B. Pursley.

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/3624/235) here on dsp.SE,